# NHibernate.Caches.Velocity change cache name

Tags: nhibernate, appfabric

We have noticed that Velocity cache name in NHibernate.Caches.Velocity.VelocityClient is hardcoded to "nhibernate"

```
private const string CacheName = "nhibernate";
.
.
.
cache = cacheCluster.GetCache(CacheName);
```

Is there a patch which enables changing cache name from configuration file. It would be good that our apps use caches with different names.

Answer (score 0):

[AppFabric: Could not contact the cache service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233792/appfabric-could-not-contact-the-cache-service)