# AppFabric: Could not contact the cache service

Tags: nhibernate, appfabric

**Update:** I have now implemented this properly. For more information see my [blog post](http://www.sharpcoder.co.uk/post/2012/01/04/NHibernateCachesAppFabric.aspx) about it.

I'm trying to use AppFabric with NHibernate as my second level cache provider but I'm getting the following error: **ErrorCode:Initialization: Could not contact the cache service. Contact administrator and refer to product help documentation for possible reasons.**

I presume that the problem is with my configuration in web.config:

```
    <section name="dcacheClient" 
             type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core"
             allowLocation="true" 
             allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
...
  <dcacheClient deployment="routing" localCache="False">
    <localCache isEnabled="false" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" />
    <hosts>
      <host name="localhost" cachePort="22233" cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" />
    </hosts>
  </dcacheClient>
```

I've downloaded the NHibernate.Caches source code to try and discover where the problem lies and the exception is being thrown in the VelocityClient constructor when the GetCache method is called:

```
  public VelocityClient(string regionName, IDictionary<string, string> properties)
  {
      region = regionName.GetHashCode().ToString(); //because the region name length is limited
      var cacheCluster = new CacheFactory();
      cache = cacheCluster.GetCache(CacheName);
      try
      {
          cache.CreateRegion(region, true);
      }
      catch (CacheException) {}
  }
```

If I add a watch to the cacheCluster variable, I can find a _servers private variable which has one System.Data.Caching.EndpointID which has the MyURI property set to net.tcp://localhost:22234/AppFabricCachingServive which I presume has come from the configuration in web.config.

If you don't know the exact cause of the problem but have some ideas on how to go about troubleshooting this problem, that would be much appreciated as well.

**Additional Info**

---

I get the following results from the command, `Get-CacheHostConfig  -HostName  tn-staylor-02  -CachePort  22233`:

```
HostName        : tn-staylor-02
ClusterPort     : 22234
CachePort       : 22233
ArbitrationPort : 22235
ReplicationPort : 22236
Size            : 3001 MB
ServiceName     : AppFabricCachingService
HighWatermark   : 90%
LowWatermark    : 70%
IsLeadHost      : True
```

So I think the values I've got configured in web.config are OK.

---

Googling this problem and investigating how to set up AppFabric in the first place, I have come across two slightly different ways of how to configure the cache in web.config. The way I have described above and the way Hanselman has it in his [AppFabric blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx)

I actually started with it like this however, I got the following error which is how I came to have it configured how I have it now:

ErrorCode:"dcacheClient" tag not specified in the application configuration file. Specify valid tag in configuration file.

---

Full stack trace of the exception that gets thrown in VelocityClient:

System.Data.Caching.CacheException occurred
  Message="ErrorCode:\"dcacheClient\" tag not specified in the application configuration file. Specify valid tag in configuration file."
  Source="CacheBaseLibrary"
  ErrorCode="ERRCMC0004"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Caching.ClientConfigFile.ThrowException(String errorCode, String param)
       at System.Data.Caching.ClientConfigReader.GetDeployementMode()
       at System.Data.Caching.ClientConfigurationManager.InitializeDepMode(ClientConfigReader cfr)
       at System.Data.Caching.ClientConfigurationManager.Initialize(String path)
       at System.Data.Caching.ClientConfigurationManager..ctor()
       at System.Data.Caching.CacheFactory.InitCacheFactory()
       at System.Data.Caching.CacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName)
       at NHibernate.Caches.Velocity.VelocityClient..ctor(String regionName, IDictionary`2 properties) in C:\Source\Projects\NHibernate.contrib\trunk\src\NHibernate.Caches\Velocity\NHibernate.Caches.Velocity\VelocityClient.cs:line 67
  InnerException:

---

**EDIT**: Added output from `get-cachehost` as requested by @PhilPursglove

Output from `get-cachehost`:

```
HostName : CachePort      Service Name            Service Status Version Info
--------------------      ------------            -------------- ------------
tn-staylor-02:22233       AppFabricCachingService UP             1 [1,1][1,1]
```

---

**SOLUTION**: @PhilPursglove was spot on. The NHibernate velocity provider was using old dll's so upgrading them and making a few code changes resolved my problems. I thought I would include my complete solution here.

1. Downloaded the NHibernate.contrib source from the SVN repository at https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk
2. Opened up the NHibernate.Caches.Everything solution and removed the references to the old velocity dll's from the NHibernate.Caches.Velocity project.
3. Added references to the App Fabric dll's which were installed when I installed App Fabric. This isn't the normal case of adding a reference to an assembly in the GAC, but [this article describes how to do it](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/adding-a-reference-to-the-microsoft-applicationserver-caching-client-assembly.aspx).
4. Adding the new references meant that the VelocityClient class no longer compiled. With a little bit of help from [this](http://pastebin.com/f78b1132c) I came up with the version of VelocityClient.cs below.
5. I added a reference to the new version of NHibernate.Caches.Velocity to my project, made the changes below to my configuration and everything worked.

**VelocityClient.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;
using log4net;
using NHibernate.Cache;
using CacheException = Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException;
using CacheFactory = Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory;

namespace NHibernate.Caches.Velocity
{
    public class VelocityClient : ICache
    {
        private const string CacheName = "nhibernate";
        private static readonly ILog log;
        private readonly DataCache cache;
        private readonly string region;
        private Dictionary<string, DataCacheLockHandle> locks = new Dictionary<string, DataCacheLockHandle>();

        static VelocityClient()
        {
            log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (VelocityClient));
        }

        public VelocityClient() : this("nhibernate", null) {}

        public VelocityClient(string regionName) : this(regionName, null) {}

        public VelocityClient(string regionName, IDictionary<string, string> properties)
        {
            region = regionName.GetHashCode().ToString(); //because the region name length is limited
            var cacheCluster = new CacheFactory();
            cache = cacheCluster.GetCache(CacheName);
            try
            {
                cache.CreateRegion(region);
            }
            catch (CacheException) {}
        }

        #region ICache Members

        public object Get(object key)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.DebugFormat("fetching object {0} from the cache", key);
            }

            DataCacheItemVersion version = null;
            return cache.Get(key.ToString(), out version, region);
        }

        public void Put(object key, object value)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key", "null key not allowed");
            }
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "null value not allowed");
            }

            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.DebugFormat("setting value for item {0}", key);
            }

            cache.Put(key.ToString(), value, region);
        }

        public void Remove(object key)
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            }
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.DebugFormat("removing item {0}", key);
            }

            if (Get(key.ToString()) != null)
            {
                cache.Remove(region, key.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            cache.ClearRegion(region);
        }

        public void Destroy()
        {
            Clear();
        }

        public void Lock(object key)
        {
            DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle = null;

            if (Get(key.ToString()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    cache.GetAndLock(key.ToString(), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout), out lockHandle, region);
                    locks.Add(key.ToString(), lockHandle);
                }
                catch (CacheException) {}
            }
        }

        public void Unlock(object key)
        {
            DataCacheLockHandle lockHandle = null;

            if (Get(key.ToString()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (locks.ContainsKey(key.ToString()))
                    {
                        cache.Unlock(key.ToString(), locks[key.ToString()], region);
                        locks.Remove(key.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (CacheException) {}
            }
        }

        public long NextTimestamp()
        {
            return Timestamper.Next();
        }

        public int Timeout
        {
            get { return Timestamper.OneMs * 60000; } // 60 seconds
        }

        public string RegionName
        {
            get { return region; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**NHibernate.config:**

```
...
    <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.Velocity.VelocityProvider, NHibernate.Caches.Velocity</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
...
```

**web.config**

```
...
    <section name="dataCacheClient"
             type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             allowLocation="true"
             allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
...
  <dataCacheClient>
    <!-- cache host(s) -->
    <hosts>
      <host
         name="localhost"
         cachePort="22233"/>
    </hosts>
  </dataCacheClient>
...
```

I didn't make any further changes to my App Fabric configuration or anything.

Comment: Is your cache running? What's the output from `get-cachehost`?

Comment: @PhilPursglove, yes the cache is running and I have added the output from get-cachehost to the original question. Thanks for taking the time to comment

Comment: Glad you fixed it! You should submit those NHibernate changes back to the trunk so no-one else gets this problem.

Comment: @s1mm0t I'm looking at using AppFabric as a second level cache.  Did this work out well for you?

Comment: Yes it Is working out well. I keep meaning to do do a blog post about my experiences

Comment: @s1mm0t you should and either submit to nhcontrib or log an issue detailing this.  good work.

Comment: @s1mm0t I've followed your lead and got the  NHibernate.Caches.Velocity.Tests working with my local AppFabric instance.  All except TestRemove, it simply seems not to remove the item given a key.  cache.Clear wipes everything fine but not .Remove

Comment: Yes I would love to submit this fix to nhcontrib but I have contacted them about getting permission but haven't heard anything back...

Comment: I have to admit that I couldn't get the tests running, so it is entirely possible that the tests won't all pass with the code above.

Comment: @s1mm0t i got them all running bar the remove method. I'll let you know if i do. I take it you've seen your provider remove things from the cache?  Or probably a better question, has it worked fine as a second level cache?

Comment: @dove Yes it is working fine as a second level cache

Comment: I emailed Ayende about this in November, his response was that perhaps the AppFabric cache should be removed from nhcontrib, but I was unclear on whether he was going to do it - like @s1mm0t I can't do this myself!

Comment: Hi, just want to say "Thank you!!" and let you know that I have followed your solution, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, I picked up a small bug in VelocityClient.cs, in the Remove(object key) method, the remove line should be:

cache.Remove(key.ToString(), region);

Comment: Hey! Thanks... that's all I have to say...

Comment: Hi, I've been working through you're solution, and I've made some progress, however I'm stuck with the following error at runtime when starting my project (debug) on my local machine:

"Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache."

Any idea's what this could be, have I missed somthing in the configuration? If I do a 'get-cache' in powershell, I get a cache with a name 'default' with no regions.

Comment: Ignore me, I see the cache name is hard coded into VelocityClient.cs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two possible culprits here:

1. In your web.config under the `hosts` element, you're listing `localhost` - I'd try swapping that out for the actual server name `tn-staylor-02`
2. That exception stack trace refers to `CacheBaseLibrary` - I don't know a great deal (read: anything!) about NHibernate but I would hazard a guess that that cache might not be built with the release version of AppFabric - CacheBaseLibrary was an assembly that appeared in the CTPs and betas but I didn't think it was used in the RTM version. Note that in the section element for `dcacheclient`, it refers to the `Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core` assembly.

Comment: I have tried using tn-staylor-02 without any luck, but it does appear that you may be on to something with the cache base library. I will try swapping in the latest assemblies and will probably need to update the code as well - I will let you know how I get on.