# NHibernate 2nd level caching with AppFabric

Tags: .net, nhibernate, second-level-cache, appfabric

Has anyone used AppFabric for their second level caching?

I know it's to follow the same api as for Velocity ([nhibernate.caches.velocity](https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Caches/Velocity/)) but wanted to know if anyone already had some production experience of using it and if they knew of any particular tips or problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem I'm currently aware of is what was covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233792/appfabric-could-not-contact-the-cache-service), that the references in the Velocity cache code are out of date and need updating to the AppFabric v1 release assemblies.

Comment: We use it. Apart from the issue @PhilPursglove mentioned it should be fine.

Comment: @PhilPursglove given this as answer but long given up on app fabric.  assuming ms have absorbed most of it into azure somewhere but not explored.  you using it still?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AppFabric as second level cache but I've used [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/nhibernate-l2cache-index.html) as second level cache for Nhibernate and results were quite satisfactory.By default NHibernation provides a stand alone InProc (in process) first-level (L1) cache, or session-level cache. However in addition, , NHibernate also supports a second-level cache to be plugged in to exploit the benefits of a sophisticated enterprise-grade caching infrastructure.